# ListDensityPlot erroneously showing flat regions (NOT plot range issue)

Tags: plotting, functions

I have a dataset (listed below). I'm trying to plot the dataset using ListDensity plot;

```
ListDensityPlot[dataset, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> All]
```

When I sample infrequently, so that the data set is small, everything is fine ...

[image: ListDensityPlot with small dataset]

But when I sample more frequently, ListDensityPlot creates a flat region (beige) that is NOT present in the data ...

[image: ListDensityPlot with larger dataset]

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

For reference, the two datasets are

**Small:**

```
{{25, 0., 3.25504}, {25, 0.025, 3.03122}, {25, 0.05, 2.80847}, {25, 
  0.075, 2.5882}, {25, 0.1, 2.37189}, {75, 0., 3.34178}, {75, 0.025, 
  2.65662}, {75, 0.05, 2.00862}, {75, 0.075, 1.43803}, {75, 0.1, 
  0.974322}, {125, 0., 3.35954}, {125, 0.025, 2.22964}, {125, 0.05, 
  1.27735}, {125, 0.075, 0.630202}, {125, 0.1, 0.274333}}
```

**Large:**

```
{{25, 0., 3.25504}, {25, 0.01, 3.16547}, {25, 0.02, 3.07594}, {25, 
  0.03, 2.98654}, {25, 0.04, 2.89735}, {25, 0.05, 2.80847}, {25, 0.06,
   2.71998}, {25, 0.07, 2.63198}, {25, 0.08, 2.54457}, {25, 0.09, 
  2.45784}, {25, 0.1, 2.37189}, {75, 0., 3.34178}, {75, 0.01, 
  3.06587}, {75, 0.02, 2.792}, {75, 0.03, 2.52271}, {75, 0.04, 
  2.26069}, {75, 0.05, 2.00862}, {75, 0.06, 1.76907}, {75, 0.07, 
  1.54428}, {75, 0.08, 1.33612}, {75, 0.09, 1.14588}, {75, 0.1, 
  0.974322}, {125, 0., 3.35954}, {125, 0.01, 2.8982}, {125, 0.02, 
  2.44732}, {125, 0.03, 2.01923}, {125, 0.04, 1.62598}, {125, 0.05, 
  1.27735}, {125, 0.06, 0.979442}, {125, 0.07, 0.733926}, {125, 0.08, 
  0.538418}, {125, 0.09, 0.387549}, {125, 0.1, 0.274333}, {175, 0., 
  3.36719}, {175, 0.01, 2.72209}, {175, 0.02, 2.1072}, {175, 0.03, 
  1.55594}, {175, 0.04, 1.09479}, {175, 0.05, 0.73559}, {175, 0.06, 
  0.474159}, {175, 0.07, 0.294993}, {175, 0.08, 0.17825}, {175, 0.09, 
  0.105215}, {175, 0.1, 0.0609632}, {225, 0., 3.37143}, {225, 0.01, 
  2.54503}, {225, 0.02, 1.78468}, {225, 0.03, 1.15598}, {225, 0.04, 
  0.693407}, {225, 0.05, 0.38893}, {225, 0.06, 0.206657}, {225, 0.07, 
  0.10536}, {225, 0.08, 0.0520935}, {225, 0.09, 0.0251863}, {225, 0.1,
   0.011985}, {275, 0., 3.37413}, {275, 0.01, 2.36971}, {275, 0.02, 
  1.48715}, {275, 0.03, 0.829508}, {275, 0.04, 0.416294}, {275, 0.05, 
  0.19227}, {275, 0.06, 0.0836399}, {275, 0.07, 0.0349119}, {275, 
  0.08, 0.0141767}, {275, 0.09, 0.00566518}, {275, 0.1, 
  0.00225865}, {325, 0., 3.376}, {325, 0.01, 2.19763}, {325, 0.02, 
  1.21954}, {325, 0.03, 0.576578}, {325, 0.04, 0.239136}, {325, 0.05, 
  0.0904544}, {325, 0.06, 0.0322287}, {325, 0.07, 0.0110721}, {325, 
  0.08, 0.00374375}, {325, 0.09, 0.00128508}, {325, 0.1, 
  0.000478527}, {375, 0., 3.37736}, {375, 0.01, 2.02993}, {375, 0.02, 
  0.984654}, {375, 0.03, 0.389649}, {375, 0.04, 0.132673}, {375, 0.05,
   0.041089}, {375, 0.06, 0.0120503}, {375, 0.07, 0.0034607}, {375, 
  0.08, 0.00102748}, {375, 0.09, 0.000357863}, {375, 0.1, 
  0.000177356}, {425, 0., 3.3784}, {425, 0.01, 1.86755}, {425, 0.02, 
  0.783308}, {425, 0.03, 0.257056}, {425, 0.04, 0.0716749}, {425, 
  0.05, 0.0182314}, {425, 0.06, 0.00445654}, {425, 0.07, 
  0.00112607}, {425, 0.08, 0.000352191}, {425, 0.09, 
  0.000177144}, {425, 0.1, 0.000138316}, {475, 0., 3.37922}, {475, 
  0.01, 1.71129}, {475, 0.02, 0.614545}, {475, 0.03, 0.166205}, {475, 
  0.04, 0.0379629}, {475, 0.05, 0.00798815}, {475, 0.06, 
  0.00168463}, {475, 0.07, 0.000435347}, {475, 0.08, 
  0.00019679}, {475, 0.09, 0.000152387}, {475, 0.1, 
  0.000144276}, {525, 0., 3.37987}, {525, 0.01, 1.56184}, {525, 0.02, 
  0.476022}, {525, 0.03, 0.105707}, {525, 0.04, 0.0198299}, {525, 
  0.05, 0.00350805}, {525, 0.06, 0.000699413}, {525, 0.07, 
  0.000242271}, {525, 0.08, 0.000170453}, {525, 0.09, 
  0.000159445}, {525, 0.1, 0.000157788}, {575, 0., 3.38041}, {575, 
  0.01, 1.41975}, {575, 0.02, 0.364477}, {575, 0.03, 0.0663431}, {575,
   0.04, 0.0102764}, {575, 0.05, 0.00158704}, {575, 0.06, 
  0.000360887}, {575, 0.07, 0.000196785}, {575, 0.08, 
  0.000175559}, {575, 0.09, 0.000172879}, {575, 0.1, 
  0.000172546}, {625, 0., 3.38086}, {625, 0.01, 1.2855}, {625, 0.02, 
  0.276191}, {625, 0.03, 0.0412046}, {625, 0.04, 0.00532472}, {625, 
  0.05, 0.000779192}, {625, 0.06, 0.000252417}, {625, 0.07, 
  0.000194398}, {625, 0.08, 0.000188216}, {625, 0.09, 
  0.000187573}, {625, 0.1, 0.000187507}, {675, 0., 3.38124}, {675, 
  0.01, 1.15941}, {675, 0.02, 0.207377}, {675, 0.03, 0.0253918}, {675,
   0.04, 0.00279299}, {675, 0.05, 0.000448124}, {675, 0.06, 
  0.000224708}, {675, 0.07, 0.000204446}, {675, 0.08, 
  0.000202667}, {675, 0.09, 0.000202514}, {675, 0.1, 
  0.000202501}, {725, 0., 3.38157}, {725, 0.01, 1.04169}, {725, 0.02, 
  0.154462}, {725, 0.03, 0.0155672}, {725, 0.04, 0.00151486}, {725, 
  0.05, 0.000318814}, {725, 0.06, 0.00022505}, {725, 0.07, 
  0.000218045}, {725, 0.08, 0.000217539}, {725, 0.09, 
  0.000217503}, {725, 0.1, 0.0002175}, {775, 0., 3.38185}, {775, 0.01,
   0.932418}, {775, 0.02, 0.114246}, {775, 0.03, 0.00952547}, {775, 
  0.04, 0.000878491}, {775, 0.05, 0.000274063}, {775, 0.06, 
  0.000235054}, {775, 0.07, 0.000232652}, {775, 0.08, 
  0.000232509}, {775, 0.09, 0.000232501}, {775, 0.1, 0.0002325}, {825,
   0., 3.38209}, {825, 0.01, 0.831578}, {825, 0.02, 0.0839943}, {825, 
  0.03, 0.00584262}, {825, 0.04, 0.000567567}, {825, 0.05, 
  0.00026447}, {825, 0.06, 0.00024836}, {825, 0.07, 
  0.000247542}, {825, 0.08, 0.000247502}, {825, 0.09, 
  0.0002475}, {825, 0.1, 0.0002475}, {875, 0., 3.3823}, {875, 0.01, 
  0.739036}, {875, 0.02, 0.0614382}, {875, 0.03, 0.00361527}, {875, 
  0.04, 0.000420403}, {875, 0.05, 0.000269401}, {875, 0.06, 
  0.000262788}, {875, 0.07, 0.000262512}, {875, 0.08, 
  0.0002625}, {875, 0.09, 0.0002625}, {875, 0.1, 0.0002625}, {925, 0.,
   3.38249}, {925, 0.01, 0.654567}, {925, 0.02, 0.0447492}, {925, 
  0.03, 0.00227834}, {925, 0.04, 0.000355108}, {925, 0.05, 
  0.000280296}, {925, 0.06, 0.000277596}, {925, 0.07, 
  0.000277503}, {925, 0.08, 0.0002775}, {925, 0.09, 0.0002775}, {925, 
  0.1, 0.0002775}, {975, 0., 3.38266}, {975, 0.01, 0.57787}, {975, 
  0.02, 0.0324836}, {975, 0.03, 0.00148225}, {975, 0.04, 
  0.000330517}, {975, 0.05, 0.000293629}, {975, 0.06, 
  0.000292532}, {975, 0.07, 0.000292501}, {975, 0.08, 
  0.0002925}, {975, 0.09, 0.0002925}, {975, 0.1, 0.00029216}, {1025, 
  0., 3.38281}, {1025, 0.01, 0.508576}, {1025, 0.02, 
  0.0235217}, {1025, 0.03, 0.00101271}, {1025, 0.04, 
  0.000326068}, {1025, 0.05, 0.000307955}, {1025, 0.06, 
  0.000307511}, {1025, 0.07, 0.0003075}, {1025, 0.08, 
  0.0003075}, {1025, 0.09, 0.000307114}, {1025, 0.1, 0.000307224}}
```

Comment: Look carefully at `ListPointPlot3D[dataset, PlotRange -> All]`; it'll show you the issue with your `dataset`.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: `ListDensityPlot[Log[dataset], ... ]` looks nice.

Comment: This is a problem with the triangulation algorithm which does not like extreme aspect ratios. The simplest workaround is to rescale one of the axes e.g. `dataset[[All, 2]] *= 10000;`

Comment: Simon Woods' solution identifies the problem and is a neat workaround! Logging the dataset works because it reduces the difference between the difference in the aspect ratio. Thanks, this is great!